# Optimize query Eloquent laravel for thousands records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with a query in Laravel with many records, because it is so slow.

I have a table **users** that has **4934** records.

I have table of relations that for example is named **user_relation_values** that has **17482** records.

I have a table **values** that has **20495** records.

Now I receive,from front end, **N** id of users, so I could receive 1 id or 4934 ids or 2000 ids or 1000 ids, so I don't know how many ids I will receive.

I have to return, starting by ids received, the relations of model users with id.

So in My backend I have a function like this:

```
$users= $request->input('users');
$usersValues = array();
foreach ($users as $user){
   $o = User::find($owner['id']);
   $o->values;
   $owersProperties[] = $o;
}
```

I have the relations in My User model:

```
public function values(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Values');
    }
```

**I have put The various indexes on tables** but the query Is so slow if I receive the all id.

If I receive all 4934 ids the query takes more than 20 seconds, but I read that someone make query for milions of records in just over 5 seconds.

How can I optimize my table or my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your example code, you’re query users in a loop (*n* queries), and *then* also querying values for each user. That’s going to issue an exponential number of queries. Instead, you should query the users and eager-load the values relationship.

If you’re getting an array of user IDs as input, then you can pass that to Eloquent’s `find()` method:

```
$users = User::find($request->input('users'));
```

You should also eager-load the `values` relationship if you plan on using it in a loop:

```
$users = User::with('values')->find($request->input('users'));
```

This should dramatically reduce the number of queries you issue.

Comment: Hello, thankyou, I didn't know that I can find for array value, I have tried with  $users = User::with('values')->find($request->input('users')); and it is more fast but it take still more 15 sec.

Comment: @LorenzoBerti It might be worth installed https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar, and then you’ll be able to see what queries your application’s issuing for any one page.

Comment: thankyou is very useful, with this I discovered that in reality the query is very fast, 630ms and the problem may be a response because I have in statements executed 4.61s, and response time in console: 17.67s

Comment: the stranger thing that if I copy one query printed, in phpmyadmin return in 0.2 seconds instead inconsole I read 4 second